# How to Pass a Parameter to a DataContext?

Tags: c#, wpf, datacontext, staticresource

Is possible to pass some data to a Binding Source/Data Context via XAML?

In my particular case, I want the Binding Source to be given a reference to the Window that created it.

For example:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
    x:Name="MyWindow">

    <Window.Resources>
        <local:MarginDataContext x:Key="MyDC"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <!-- I want to pass in "MyWindow" to "MyDC" here... -->
    <Grid Margin="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyDC}, Path=My_Margin}" /> 
</Window>
```

Note: MarginDataContext is my own creation, so if this involves adding constructor parameters or something, that would work fine!

**Update:** I would like a solution that adheres to some requirements specific to my project:

- Does not use the x:Reference extension.
- Use as little code behind as possible (I want to be able to do most of the work in XAML).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways I can think of to do this, 1) using a parameter for the MarginDataContext constructor and 2) using DataContextChanged in the code behind.

Method 1: Parameterized MarginDataContext
See [x:Arguments Directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee795382.aspx) and [x:Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee795380%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on MSDN for more information

```
public class MarginDataContext
{
    public WindowInstance { get; set; }
    ...
}

<!-- xaml -->
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MarginDataContext
        x:Key="MyDC"
        WindowInstance="{x:Reference MyWindow}" />
    <!-- or possibly (not sure about this) -->
    <local:MarginDataContext
        x:Key="MyDC"
        WindowInstance="{Binding ElementName=MyWindow}" />
    <!-- or even (again, not sure about this) -->
    <local:MarginDataContext
        x:Key="MyDC"
        WindowInstance="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Method 2: Using code behind. See [DataContextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontextchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information.

```
public class MyWindow : Window
{
    ...
    public MyWindow()
    {
        // Attach event handler
        this.DataContextChanged += HandleDataContextChanged;

        // You may have to directly call the Handler as sometimes
        // DataContextChanged isn't raised on new windows, but only
        // when the DataContext actually changes.
    }

    void HandleDataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dc = DataContext as MarginDataContext;
        if (dc != null)
        {
            // Assuming there is a 'MyWindow' property on MarginDataContext
            dc.MyWindow = this;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan! BlueM's answer worked pretty well for my needs, so I didn't actually give this stuff a try. May come back to it at some point, and will post the result here. Thanks again!

Comment: Ah, I see BlueM's answer is equivalent to #1 except he has the correct syntax. :)

Comment: I haven't tried this, but I thought of another possibility without using x:Reference. Please try the {Binding} in #1 and see if it works.

Answer (score 2):

You can access any property of your MarginDataContext in XAML. So lets say you create a `WindowInstance` property, you can then simply assign it on construction of the MarginDataContext by using `x:Reference`:

```
<local:MarginDataContext x:Key="MyDC" WindowInstance="{x:Reference MyWindow}"/>
```

Comment: Actually... This doesn't totally work for me. In my case I can't use the x:Reference extension :( Any ideas on how to do it without using x:Reference?

Comment: The platform I am using does not support the x:Reference extension. Your solution totally works running standard WPF, but in my special case I cannot use that extension, unfortunately.

Comment: I see `x:Reference` is part of XAML 2009 even though the namespace of XAML 2006 does accepted it.